# django-nonrel and the admin page

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-admin, django-nonrel

I am trying to set-up the Django admin suite for my site on AppEngine and it is not working.  I am using the django-nonrel setup with .  The rest of my site seems to work fine but I need to get the admin working so I can start working with the datastore.

Here is the error I get:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist.
```

My url patterns includes this pattern:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

My settings include:

```
'autoload',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'djangotoolbox',
'djangoappengine',
'myapp',
```

My confusion is that this is installed and it is there so I am not sure why it's failing on that page.  To prove I was not loosing my mind I copied the URL pattern code from a working site and looked at the code for the admin module but still no luck.

Thanks for any insight anyone has.

RB

Comment: I meant to add:  "I am using the django-nonrel setup with the configuration the ABP guys suggest."

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, simply comment out 'django.contrib.sites', in installed apps...
This should work now !

Comment: Yes!  This was the problem that I had too.. took me a couple hours before I stumbled on your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Yep its a little tricky to set it up, I would recommend using allButtonsPressed and GAE 1.5.3.

Comment: Would love to but can't figure out how to roll it back  to 1.5.3.

Comment: if you use buildout there is recipe for that [appfy.recipe.gae:sdk](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appfy.recipe.gae/).

Or you can install gae 1.5.3 manualy and change your PATH..