# Django-nonrel cannot login into the admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I have a Django app which I am trying to get to Django-nonrel so that I can get it on GAE. The problem though is that numerous times have I tried creating superuser for the admin interface still when I do syncdb, it shows me:

> You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have
>   any superusers defined.

everytime.Also, I am never able to login into my admin interface by the created superuser. Also, when I do this:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
[]
```

SO no users are created it seems. I tried to look for the solution and and had a look at a few questions like these:

[django-nonrel and the admin page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498837/django-nonrel-and-the-admin-page)

and a few others. Didn't help either. I would like to mention that I am using zip downloaded version of django-nonrel 1.6 and djangoappengine by copying them in my project directory

I also tried creating a user by the python manage.py shell and granting it is_staff= True.

The user is now being shown in the User.objects.all() but I cannot still not login by this user.

Comment: just do python manage.py --help there you willl see command for creating superuser.. create superuser from that and try once

Comment: I have done **python manage.py createsuperuser** several times still no super users are created and the syncdb problem. @aryan

Comment: Have u defined AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings ? If yes then try python manage.py makemigrations auth.User and migrate it . If it dont work delete the database and do syncdb again.. I dont know whats causing your problem jsut give it  a try

Comment: I'm using django-nonrel 1.6 makemigrations does not work with manage.py here shows this:
Unknown command: 'makemigrations'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: @HarshitKumar Facing same issue, did you find any solution?